# Missing data converted to zero in Openoffice

Tags: excel, qgis, openoffice-calc

I am using Quantum GIS (QGIS) to map demographic & economic data, for example, from the US Census (factfinder2.census.gov). I store and manipulate the datasets in Excel; Census data downloads as csv files. QGIS uses dbf files to store data, which I open with OpenOffice. While I can open dbf files in Excel, QGIS doesn't like what Excel does to the file. The easiest way I have found to do this is to copy/paste the data from Excel into the dbf file open in OpenOffice.

The problem is that any missing data, blank cells in Excel, must stay "missing," but when I copy/paste the data from Excel into the OpenOffice dbf file, then close and reopen the dbf file, OpenOffice has converted all of my blank cells to zeros. I can't find a way to keep missing data as blank cells (or some other designation of missingness, like NA in R).

For example, if I have QGIS mapping a change in poverty status for the counties in a state, say, between -10% to +10%, I need to be able to distinguish a zero, no change, from 'missing data.' Right now all of my 'missing data' is showing up as 'no change' so I can't tell which is which, even by looking at the original dbf file since the missing data shows up as zeros.

Comment: I think the issue is the DBF format, which does not support `NULL`. I don't know QGIS, be if it can't work with other data sources, I'd use another tool !

Comment: @pnuts--that would seem like a logical approach.  However, OpenOffice (and LibreOffice) detects string/text anomalies and replaces them with zeros, apparently believing they are errors and self-correcting rather than asking what the user wants to do.  I can't find that there is a character for OO (or LO) that tells the software "this is a null cell"

Comment: All of the numerical variables have a format similar to this: "varname, N, 5, 2".  As far as I know that is my only option, since changing it to a string field (C) prevents that variable from being used for calculations when I open it up in QGIS.